# How to remove all attributes from html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, text-processing, text-parsing

I have raw html with some css classes inside for various tags.

Example:

Input:

```
<p class="opener" itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque molestias natus iste labore a accusamus dolorum vel.</p>
```

and I would like to get just plain html like:

Output:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque molestias natus iste labore a accusamus dolorum vel.</p>
```

I do not know names of these classes. I need to do this in JavaScript (node.js).

Any idea?

Comment: why does the HTML have these classes - is it generated from a CMS or similar, and if not, can it be removed from the source?

Comment: I'd like to suggest you change your title to "How do I remove all attributes from an HTML tag?" as it actually seems to have nothing to do with "css references", whatever those are.

Comment: In the example `itemprop="description"` is not a CSS attribute, but an HTML element property. I would guess you want to look for an HTML parser of some kind instead, as attributes are sometimes necessary for HTML elements (such as `<link>` and `<attr>`).

Comment: You need a HTML parser that turns that string into nodes and parses it, something like [**cheerio**](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio)

Comment: `itemprop` is not a css class. Do you simply want to remove all attributes? Also, some classes might not only be used for CSS

Comment: @AlexHighHigh html is scraped by node.js scraper using cheerio from already styled website

Comment: @Bergi, RadGH Yes, I want remove all attributes, sorry for poor description

Comment: @adeneo any idea how to accomplish that with cheerio?

Comment: @Pavel - Sure give me a second to post an answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done with Cheerio, as I noted in the comments.
To remove all attributes on all elements, you'd do:

```
var html = '<p class="opener" itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque molestias natus iste labore a accusamus dolorum vel.</p>';

var $ = cheerio.load(html);   // load the HTML

$('*').each(function() {      // iterate over all elements
    this.attribs = {};     // remove all attributes
});

var html = $.html();          // get the HTML back
```

Comment: Doesn't work until removing the `[0]`. i.e., `this.attribs = {};`

Comment: I guess that depends on what `this` is, but three years ago when I wrote this it did work with `[0]` in Cheerio.

Comment: @CarsonIp yeah removing the [0] makes it work, great tho thanks

Comment: need to add new library. As @MattDiamant mentioned - 
1. create new node 
2. .add value of old node

Answer (score 5):

I would create a new element, using the tag name and the `innerHTML` of that element. You can then replace the old element with the new one, or do whatever you like with the `newEl` as in the code below:

```
// Get the current element
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

// Create a new element (in this case, a <p> tag)
var newEl = document.createElement(el.nodeName);

// Assign the new element the contents of the old tag
newEl.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;

// Replace the old element with newEl, or do whatever you like with it
```

Comment: How do you create elements without a DOM, this is Node ?

Comment: Thanks, this solution is actually your, so thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution to this problem in vanilla JS:

```
html.replace(/\s*\S*\="[^"]+"\s*/gm, "");
```

The script removes all attributes from a string named `html` using a simple regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps some regex in js could pluck out those css tags and then output the stripped down version?  thats if i'm understanding your question corre

Comment: If you're going to use javascript, parsing your HTML with regex could lead to lots of problems, and would be pretty complicated.

Comment: [Cannot parse html with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just use Notepad++ and a quick "Find/Replace" action with a blank space will be the fastest way, instead of thinking in a parser or something similar.

Comment: What would your Find search be?

Comment: You are right Matt. If he needs to do it programatically and he doesn't know the name of the classes, so my approach is not correct.

Comment: adeneo answer is the better one I think. +1

Comment: Thanks, but what will now work - it have to be JavaScript (the best node.js program).

Answer (score 0):

improvise this:

```
$('.some_div').each(function(){
    class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).removeClass(class_name)})
```

Comment: no need to do it on server side. client side on some event like after you have loaded/changed the data in that container. bind the event to body.

Comment: But the question is specifically tagged node.js, and why do you assume it's even sent to a browser

Comment: You may do that with cheerio = jQuery api implementation for node.js
Good hint, thanks! But I do not know '.some_div'

Answer (score 0):

In python, do like this but provide a list of files and tags instead of the hard coded ones, then wrap in a for loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import re
f=open('fileWithHtml','r')

for line in f.readlines():
        line = re.sub('<p\s(.*)>[^<]', '<p>', line)
        print(line)
```

Most probably, this can be easily translated into JavaScript for nodejs

Comment: The question asked for a node.js script, not for python :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically parse the the elements using a DOM (or SAX, depending on what you want to do) parser and remove all the style attributes met.

On JavaScript, you could use HTML DOM removeAttribute() Method.

```
<script>
  function myFunction()
  {
    document.getElementsByClassName("your div class")[0].removeAttribute("style"); 
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide simple example (JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing the client-side *(browser)* version as this answer came up when I googled **remove HTML attributes**:

```
// grab the element you want to modify
var el = document.querySelector('p');

// get its attributes and cast to array, then loop through
Array.prototype.slice.call(el.attributes).forEach(function(attr) {

    // remove each attribute
    el.removeAttribute(attr.name);
});
```

As a function:

```
function removeAttributes(el) {

    // get its attributes and cast to array, then loop through
    Array.prototype.slice.call(el.attributes).forEach(function(attr) {

        // remove each attribute
        el.removeAttribute(attr.name);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$ = cheerio.load(htmlAsString);

const result = $("*")
 // specify each attribute to remove, "*" as wildcard does not work
.removeAttr("class")
.removeAttr("itemprop")
.html();
// if you also wanted to remove the inner text for some reason, comment out the previous .html() and use
//.text("")
//.toString();

console.log("result", result);
```